# How to get the "Indecisive" achievement?

Tags: orcs-must-die-2

The description is:

"Indecisive: Respec your character"

I've no idea how to "spec", never mind "respec" my character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To "spec" your character means to choose his/her powers.  This is done in the spellbook.

To respec, simply hit the "refund skulls" button in the spellbook.

[image]